# Sum of $nC^k$ and $k\times C^k$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

How to find

$$\sum_{k=0}^n nC^k$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^n knC^k$$

Does this help : $\sum n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}?$

Comment: I'm quite sure this has been asked many times before here...

Comment: I don't think the last line helps much. If you know the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$, set $x=1$ for the first part. For the second part, differentiate the same expansion, rest follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Binomial Theorem, we know
$$
(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k
$$
Differentiate both sides:
$$
n(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}
$$
Set $x=1$:
$$
n2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}
$$